# Using Selenium to scrape a table across multiple pages when the url doesn't change

Tags: python, selenium, web, webdriver, screen-scraping

I have been trying to write a program to scrape the statistics from www.whoscored.com and create a pandas dataframe.

I have updated the code with the help of *crookedleaf* and this is the working code:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.html import read_html
from pandas import DataFrame
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/6335/Stages/13796/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2016-2017')

summary_stats = DataFrame()

while True:

    while driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-summary"]').get_attribute('class') == 'is-updating': # driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-summary-loading"]').get_attribute('style') == 'display; block;' or
        time.sleep(1)

    table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-summary"]')
    table_html = table.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    page_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="currentPage"]').get_attribute('value')
    print('Page ' + page_number)
    df1 = read_html(table_html)[0]
    summary_stats = pd.concat([summary_stats, df1])
    next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="next"]')

    if 'disabled' in next_link.get_attribute('class'):
        break

    next_link.click()

print(summary_stats)

driver.close()
```

Now I am trying to gather the stats from the other tabs. I am really close, but the code is not exiting the loop when it should be breaking out of it. Here is the code below:

```
defensive_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="stage-top-player-stats-options"]/li[2]/a')
defensive_button.click()

defensive_stats = DataFrame()

while True:

    while driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-defensive"]').get_attribute('class') == 'is-updating': # driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-summary-loading"]').get_attribute('style') == 'display; block;' or
        time.sleep(1)

    table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-defensive"]')
    table_html = table.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    page_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-paging-defensive"]/div/input[1]').get_attribute('value')
    print('Page ' + page_number)
    df2 = read_html(table_html)[0]
    defensive_stats = pd.concat([defensive_stats, df2])
    next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-paging-defensive"]/div/dl[2]/dd[3]')

    if 'disabled' in next_link.get_attribute('class'):
        break

    next_link.click()

print(defensive_stats)
```

This code loops through all the pages, but then keeps looping through the last page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining your table's code outside of your loop. You are navigating to the next page, but not redefining your `table` and `table_html` elements. move them to the first lines after `while True`

EDIT: After making the changes to your code, my guess is due to the dynamically loaded content of the table, you it is unable to process the changes or unable to get the content due to the "loading" graphic overlay. Another thing is there may not always be 30 pages. Today, for example, there's 29, so it continuously gets the data from page 29. I modified your code to be keep running until the "next" button is no longer enabled, and i put in a wait that checks to see if the table is loading before continuing:

```
import time
from pandas.io.html import read_html
from pandas import DataFrame
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path-to-your-chromedriver)
driver.get('https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/6335/Stages/13796/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2016-2017')

df = DataFrame()

while True:

    while driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-summary"]').get_attribute('class') == 'is-updating': # driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-summary-loading"]').get_attribute('style') == 'display; block;' or
        time.sleep(1)

    table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-summary"]')
    table_html = table.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    page_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="currentPage"]').get_attribute('value')
    print('Page ' + page_number)
    df1 = read_html(table_html)[0]
    df.append(df1)
    next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="next"]')

    if 'disabled' in next_link.get_attribute('class'):
        break

    next_link.click()


print(df)

driver.close()
```

However, i am getting an empty `DataFrame` at the end of running this. I'm unfortunately not familiar enough with `pandas` to identify the issue, but it is related to `df.append()`. I ran this through with it printing the value of `df1` at each loop, and it prints the correct data, however it does not add it to the `DataFrame`. This may be something you are familiar enough with to implement the changes needed to run it completely.

EDIT 2: took me a while to figure this one out. essentially, the page's content is being dynamically loaded with javascript. the 'next' element you are declaring is still the first 'next' button you come across. each time you click a new tab, the amount of 'next' elements is increased. i have added in an edit that sucessfully navigates across all tabs (except the 'detailed' tab... hopefully you don't need this one lol). i, however, am still getting empty `DataFrame()`'s

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.html import read_html
from pandas import DataFrame
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/mdrouin/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/6335/Stages/13796/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2016-2017')

statistics = {  # this is a list of all the tabs on the page
    'summary': DataFrame(),
    'defensive': DataFrame(),
    'offensive': DataFrame(),
    'passing': DataFrame()
}

count = 0
tabs = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="stage-top-player-stats-options"]').find_elements_by_tag_name('li')  # this pulls all the tab elements
for tab in tabs[:-1]:  # iterate over the different tab sections
    section = tab.text.lower()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="stage-top-player-stats-options"]').find_element_by_link_text(section.title()).click()  # clicks the actual tab by using the dictionary's key (.proper() makes the first character in the string uppercase)
    time.sleep(3)
    while True:
        while driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-%s"]' % section).get_attribute('class') == 'is-updating':  # string formatting on the xpath to change for each section that is iterated over
            time.sleep(1)

        table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="statistics-table-%s"]' % section)  # string formatting on the xpath to change for each section that is iterated over
        table_html = table.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        df = read_html(table_html)[0]
        # print df
        pd.concat([statistics[section], df])
        next_link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="next"]')[count]  # makes sure it's selecting the correct index of 'next' items 
        if 'disabled' in next_link.get_attribute('class'):
            break
        time.sleep(5)
        next_link.click()
    count += 1


for df in statistics.values():  # iterates over the DataFrame() elemnts
    print df

driver.quit()
```

Comment: I have updated the code, but there are still problems. I would be really grateful if you took another look

Comment: @jchadwick92 check out my update to my answer and let me know if you have any issues with it

Comment: The code worked great, thank you so much. I have now moved on to the defensive section, but I am having trouble with exiting the loop, could you take another look?

Comment: @jchadwick92 try using the same declaration for `next_link`... `next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="next"]')`

Comment: I tried that and it gave me this error: ElementNotVisibleException

Comment: could you help me on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067827/selenium-trouble-with-the-section-tag?noredirect=1#comment73219321_43067827

Comment: The reason why DataFrame is empty probably lies in the fact that `read_html` returns a **list** of data frames. If you try `type(df)` you get a list.